# How to get the dictionary value out of the list in a column?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have these values in a column ("results") of a pandas dataframe. It seems to be dictionary in a list. How can I create a new column "label" to get the value 'POSITIVE' from this 'result' column?

```
Orginal column 'results'
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'results':[[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9989271759986877}],
              [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9988722801208496}]
]})
```

I want the derived column 'label' look like this.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'results':[[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9989271759986877}],
              [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9988722801208496}]],
    'label': ['POSITIVE','POSITIVE']
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a lambda function to get 'label' key of the (first) dict `[0]` of every row of the 'results' column as shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'results':[[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9989271759986877}],
              [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9988722801208496}]
]})

df['label'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['results'][0]['label'], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                             results     label
0  [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.998927175998...  POSITIVE
1  [{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.998872280120...  POSITIVE
```